# How to partition list with current and next object in every iteration using java streams?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I would like to get the next two objects from an ArrayList every iteration. I know we can achieve this using traditional for loop but just wondering if there are any other ways to do it.

For example, if I have the following list,

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

My output should be

```
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 5]
[5, 6]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `IntStream` you can iterate the `List` based on index and collect the result into `List`

```
List<List<Integer>> res = IntStream.range(0, list.size()-1)
                                   .mapToObj(i->Arrays.asList(list.get(i),list.get(i+1)))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Output :**

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Looks like this would do the job. How to achieve similar output if there is a list with non-integer data types for example if I have a custom data object?

Comment: Follow the same approach and replacing the integer list with the custom object list should give the same result. - @wintersun_x